# Stack overflow in python game

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having some trouble with a game I'm making using Tkinter. After shooting about 50 times the program crashes with the error:Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

I'm not sure what's causing this, but I know its in this part of my code.

```
    self.p1_shot_out = False

    def p1_shoot(event):

        if self.p1_shot_out == True:
            self.canvas.delete(self.laser_p1)

        self.laser_p1 = self.canvas.create_image(50, self.y_p1 +50, image=self.p1_laser)
        self.x_p1_laser = 50
        self.p1_shot_out = True

        time.sleep(.009)
        p1_shoot_move()

    def p1_shoot_move():

        if self.x_p1_laser <= 900:

            self.canvas.move(self.laser_p1,5,0)
            self.x_p1_laser += 5 
            self.canvas.update()
            time.sleep(.009)
            p1_shoot_move()
```

heres exactly whats printed to the terminal as requested:

Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x00001d54 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 963 in update
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 148 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 140 in p1_shoot
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1487 in **call**
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 963 in update
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 148 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 140 in p1_shoot
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1487 in **call**
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 963 in update
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 148 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 140 in p1_shoot
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1487 in **call**
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 963 in update
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 148 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 140 in p1_shoot
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1487 in **call**
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 963 in update
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 148 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 140 in p1_shoot
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1487 in **call**
  File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 963 in update
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 148 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\workspace\CS 108\src\project\Controller.py", line 150 in p1_shoot_move
  ...

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling p1_shoot?  I believe you are seeing this because you keep calling functions into each other if you could pull them out into a loop it could fix this issue

Comment: can you include the traceback? I'm pretty sure the cause is the fact that you recursively call `p1_shoot_move`, and python limits stack count to 1000.

Comment: @RafaelBarros  I think you would get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` in that case

Comment: @user2097159 Im calling p1_shoot when the spacebar is pressed

Comment: @Rafael Barros How exactly do I get the traceback? Im not 100% sure what that is.

Comment: @user2097159 and considering OP didn't include any traceback, that's all I can guess by looking at the code.

Comment: @Cal_9000 what was the error printed on your terminal? can you give us the full text?

Comment: @Rafael Barros I edited the post with the full error printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this looks like someone's taking the Coursera Interactive python course, so their code is not running in a normal interpreter (hence the lack of the recursion limit exception).

the problem is here:

```
   if self.x_p1_laser <= 900:
       self.canvas.move(self.laser_p1,5,0)
       self.x_p1_laser += 5 
       self.canvas.update()
       time.sleep(.009)
       p1_shoot_move() # Potential infinite self-recusion
```

Rework it as a loop

```
while self.x_p1_laser <= 900:
   self.canvas.move(self.laser_p1,5,0)
   self.x_p1_laser += 5 
   self.canvas.update()
   time.sleep(.009)
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid for not thinking of using a while loop now that ive seen it.